# Unable to properly mock method call when called from inside another class method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

```
MyClass firstClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

AnotherClass secondClass;
secondClass = PowerMockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);
PowerMockito.when(secondClass.anotherFunction(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(1);

int myInt = firstClass.myFunction();

if (myInt == 1) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

`myFunction` calls `anotherFunction` and returns the results of `anotherFunction`.

But it's not returning `1` and printing `"true`" like I would expect, instead it's still doing its real functionality.

What am I missing here?

Comment: where is second class defined in the first class?

Comment: An instance of AnotherClass is created inside myFunction then the instance is used to call secondClass.anotherFunction from inside myFunction.

Comment: Right. that means that the instance is used not the mock. You either refactor to have the second class injected, which is a clean code design or you use powermock to mock the initialization of the second class, which in my opinion is poor design.

Comment: Isn't my code mocking the initialization of the second class?  Why isn't my code using the mocked anotherFunction, how do I get myFunction to use the mocked anotherFunction instead of the real one?

Comment: No. You mock an instance, but not the instance being used in the first class because first class creates a real instance on its own.

Comment: How can I use the mocked instance instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An instance of AnotherClass is created inside myFunction then the instance is used to call secondClass.anotherFunction from inside myFunction.

Right. That means that the real instance is used, not the mock. The method under test is tightly coupled to the dependency because it creates a real instance on its own

```
public class MyClass {

    public int myFunction() {
        AnotherClass secondClass = new AnotherClass();

        int result = secondClass.anotherFunction(someValue);

        //...

        return result;
    }    
}
```

> **How can I use the mocked instance instead?**

You either refactor to have the second class injected, either via constructor or method parameter, which is a clean code design or you use powermock to mock the initialization of the second class, which in my opinion is poor design.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class) //<-- you must prepare the class creating the new instance
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        //Arrange
        int expected = 1;                          
        //Mock second class
        AnotherClass secondClass;
        secondClass = PowerMockito.mock(AnotherClass.class);
        PowerMockito.when(secondClass.anotherFunction(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(expected);

        //mocking initialization of second class withing first class
        PowerMockito.whenNew(AnotherClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(secondClass);

        MyClass firstClass = new MyClass();

        //Act
        int actual = firstClass.myFunction();

        //Assert                
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Reference [How to mock construction of new objects](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was missing the line where you mock the initialization of the second class within the first class.

Comment: @abhishekSingh to my knowledge stock Mockito does not have that functionality. Which is why powermockity was used.

Comment: through mockito directly if i am calling when followed by return it is giving me result .  But   from other class i am calling some method that method is internally calling as in first case  then it is giving me null  . I was thinking might we can do the same with spy @Nkosi

Comment: @abhishekSingh Follow explicit dependency principle and inject the dependent. Try to avoid tight coupling and this problem will be non existent.